# How to define a singleton object for a class I didn't write in Java EE?

Tags: java, scope, singleton, cdi, java-ee-7

Let's imagine I want a single `not.my.Clock` through my application:

```
public final class Clock {
  ... // business
}
```

I can write the following:

```
@Singleton
public class ClockProvider implements Supplier<Clock> {
  private Clock clock;
  @PostConstruct
  void init() {
    clock = ... ;
  }
  @Override
  public Clock get() {
    return clock;
  }
}

@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
  @Inject ClockProvider clockProvider;
  // Use clockProvider.get()
}
```

How can I define a singleton object for my whole application instead of a singleton provider, so that I can write the following code? The Java EE 7 tutorial [only speaks about singleton session bean, not singleton objects](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/ejb-basicexamples002.htm#GIPVI).

```
@RequestScoped
public class MyBean {
  @Inject Clock clock;
  // Use clock directly: no clock-provider.
}
```

If I had to write this in Guice, I'd write something like this:

```
bind(Clock.class).toInstance(...);
```

Or

```
@Provides @Singleton Clock provideClock() {
  return ... ;
}
```

Comment: Can't you extend `Clock` into a `@Singleton class SingletonClock extends Clock`?

Comment: @daniu No because I actually get the unique instance from somewhere I don't have my hand on. Also, I took `Clock` as an example, not as my real use case. But for the sake of the question, let's imagine that the `Clock` class is final as well. I'll adapt the question

Comment: use CDI `@Produces @ApplicationScoped` on `public Clock get()` method

Comment: @Rouliboy it's definitely worth an answer as it works as expected! Please make one so I can accept it.

Comment: @OlivierGrégoire : great if this helped you. I created an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `@Produces` and `@ApplicationScoped` annotations on `public Clock get()` method to produces a `Clock` singleton :

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public Clock get() {
    // your code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With CDI, you will want to go for `@ApplicationScoped` (one shared instance in your app) instead for `@Singleton` (did you mean EJB one? or CDI one?).

Then you want to do what you do with all "non-beans" which you want to turn into beans - you tell CDI how to produce such a bean.

```
@Produces
@ApplicationScoped
public Clock produceClock() {
  Clock clock = ... // any code you use to create or retrieve the instance
  return clock;
}
```

With the above you can then do `@Inject Clock clock` in your code which will call this producer in order to create the bean.

If you wish to read more on producers, it's in [this chapter in CDI spec](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/1.2/cdi-spec.html#producer_method).